# Distribution plot is showing flat pdf

Tags: python, matplotlib, statistics, distribution, data-fitting

I tried to plot the `Probability Density Function (PDF) plot` of my data after finding the best parameters, but the plot is showing a flat line instead of a curve.

- Is it a matter of scaling?
- Is it a problem of `Continuous or Discrete data`? Data file is available [here](https://filebin.net/kp8pqph396fiuh63)
- The purpose here is to get the best distribution fittings and then plot PDF function.
- My data values are so small like: `0.21, 1.117` .etc. The data statistics and PDF plots are shown below:

  [image: ![![enter image description here]

My script is given below:

```
from time import time
from datetime import datetime
start_time = datetime.now()
import pandas as pd
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.4f}'.format
import numpy as np
import pickle
import scipy
import scipy.stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data= pd.read_csv("line_RXC_data.csv",usecols=['R'],parse_dates=True, squeeze=True)
df=data

y_std=df
# del yy

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")


# Create an index array (x) for data

y=df
#
# Create an index array (x) for data

x = np.arange(len(y))
size = len(y)

#simple visualisation of the data
plt.hist(y)
plt.title("Histogram of resistance ")
plt.xlabel("Resistance data visualization ")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.show()

y_df = pd.DataFrame(y)
tt=y_df.describe()
print(tt)

dist_names = [
                'foldcauchy',
                'beta',
                'expon',
                  'exponnorm',
                'norm', 
                'lognorm',
                  'dweibull',
                'pareto',
                  'gamma'
]


x = np.arange(len(df))
size = len(df)
y_std = df
y=df
chi_square = []
p_values = []

# Set up 50 bins for chi-square test
# Observed data will be approximately evenly distrubuted aross all bins
percentile_bins = np.linspace(0,100,51)
percentile_cutoffs = np.percentile(y_std, percentile_bins)
observed_frequency, bins = (np.histogram(y_std, bins=percentile_cutoffs))
cum_observed_frequency = np.cumsum(observed_frequency)

# Loop through candidate distributions

for distribution in dist_names:
    s1 = time()
    # Set up distribution and get fitted distribution parameters
    dist = getattr(scipy.stats, distribution)
    # print("1")
    param = dist.fit(y_std)
    # print("2")
    # Obtain the KS test P statistic, round it to 5 decimal places
    p = scipy.stats.kstest(y_std, distribution, args=param)[1]
    p = np.around(p, 5)
    p_values.append(p)    
    # print("3")
    # Get expected counts in percentile bins
    # This is based on a 'cumulative distrubution function' (cdf)
    cdf_fitted = dist.cdf(percentile_cutoffs, *param[:-2], loc=param[-2], 
                          scale=param[-1])
    # print("4")
    expected_frequency = []
    for bin in range(len(percentile_bins)-1):
        expected_cdf_area = cdf_fitted[bin+1] - cdf_fitted[bin]
        expected_frequency.append(expected_cdf_area)

    # calculate chi-squared
    expected_frequency = np.array(expected_frequency) * size
    cum_expected_frequency = np.cumsum(expected_frequency)
    ss = sum (((cum_expected_frequency - cum_observed_frequency) ** 2) / cum_observed_frequency)
    chi_square.append(ss)
    print(f"chi_square {distribution} time: {time() - s1}")

#    print("std of predicted probability : ", np.std(cum_observed_frequency))   

# Collate results and sort by goodness of fit (best at top)

results = pd.DataFrame()
results['Distribution'] = dist_names
results['chi_square'] = chi_square
results['p_value'] = p_values
results.sort_values(['chi_square'], inplace=True)

# Report results

print ('\nDistributions sorted by goodness of fit:')
print ('----------------------------------------')
print (results)


#%%

# Divide the observed data into 100 bins for plotting (this can be changed)
number_of_bins = 100
bin_cutoffs = np.linspace(np.percentile(y,0), np.percentile(y,99),number_of_bins)

# Create the plot
plt.figure(figsize=(7, 4))
h = plt.hist(y, bins = bin_cutoffs, color='0.70')

# Get the top three distributions from the previous phase
number_distributions_to_plot = 5
dist_names = results['Distribution'].iloc[0:number_distributions_to_plot]


#%%
# Create an empty list to stroe fitted distribution parameters
parameters = []

# Loop through the distributions ot get line fit and paraemters

for dist_name in dist_names:
    # Set up distribution and store distribution paraemters
    dist = getattr(scipy.stats, dist_name)
    param = dist.fit(y)
    parameters.append(param)

    # Get line for each distribution (and scale to match observed data)
    pdf_fitted = dist.pdf(x, *param[:-2], loc=param[-2], scale=param[-1])
    scale_pdf = np.trapz (h[0], h[1][:-1]) / np.trapz (pdf_fitted, x)
    pdf_fitted *= scale_pdf

    # Add the line to the plot
    plt.plot(pdf_fitted, label=dist_name)

    # Set the plot x axis to contain 99% of the data
    # This can be removed, but sometimes outlier data makes the plot less clear
    plt.xlim(0,np.percentile(y,99))


# Add legend and display plotfig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,5)) 

plt.legend()
plt.title(u'Data distribution charateristics) \n' )
plt.xlabel(u'Resistance')
plt.ylabel('Frequency )')
plt.show()

# Store distribution paraemters in a dataframe (this could also be saved)
dist_parameters = pd.DataFrame()
dist_parameters['Distribution'] = (
        results['Distribution'].iloc[0:number_distributions_to_plot])
dist_parameters['Distribution parameters'] = parameters

# Print parameter results
print ('\nDistribution parameters:')
print ('------------------------')

for index, row in dist_parameters.iterrows():
    print ('\nDistribution:', row[0])
    print ('Parameters:', row[1] )
```

Comment: It does look like scaling problem. Try to get rid of that grey bars and see if it works. After that you can try adding second y-axis like here: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/api/two_scales.html.

Comment: Try `plt.hist(..., density=True)` to get the histogram scaled down. Now the y-axis of the histogram is the bin count. And the y-axis of the pdf is normalized.

Comment: You mean in this line: `h = plt.hist(y, bins = bin_cutoffs, color='0.70')`

Comment: Yes. `density=True` scales down the histogram to be more similar to the pdf.

Comment: I followed your suggestions but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the following categorical frequency analysis, you'll see that you have only 15 distinct values spread across the range with large gaps in between—not a continuum of values.  Half the observations have the value 0.211, with another ~36% occurring at the value 1.117, ~8% at 0.194, and ~4% at 0.001. I think it's a mistake to treat this as continuous data.

[image: Categorical view of data]

Comment: @pjs..Well this is an excellent demonstration of data. So, overall we can say this is discrete data? .Secondly,` Probability Density Function (PDF)` are ideal for discrete data or continuous data? Can we do the same frequency analysis in python also?

Comment: I don't know the data nor its source, but when a continuous range packs all of its data into 15 specific values, I'd call it discrete.  And no, PDFs are not appropriate for discrete data - one should use a probability mass function, which describes the probability associated with each outcome. That's what the table above is. PMFs and CDFs evaluate to probabilities, PDFs do not.  For a counterexample, consider a triangular distribution on the range (0,1) with mode 0. The PDF evaluates to f(0) = 2, proving it can't be a probability (since axiomatically all probabilities are <= 1).

Comment: I'd bet there's a library that will do something like the analysis I've done above, but I'm a statistician who is not a fan of Python so I couldn't tell you what it is.  However, it's not hard to build a dictionary that maintains a counter for the values, nor to sum all of those counts and express each value's count as a proportion of the total.

Comment: If you're looking for appropriate ways to plot categorical data, a few moments searching turned up catplot, barplot, and countplot [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/categorical.html).